# Substitute for zip command or way to zip files

Tags: bash, zip

I want to zip files using the `zip` command, but my terminal says

```
-bash: zip: command not found
```

Is there a way to get the `zip` command, or maybe use another command instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install `zip`, with Ubuntu or Debian :

```
sudo apt-get install zip
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have access to install zip, you can try `tar` instead to see if it's available.

Example to "zip" a directory:

```
tar -czf myfolder.tar.gz myfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you already have zip installed but it is not in PATH.

To add folder with 'zip to PATH, run the command below in the terminal.

```
PATH=/usr/bin/ls:$PATH
```

This works for MacOS